# when template parameter of a template template-parameter is pack expansion, gcc fails, clang succeeds

Tags: c++

```
template<class ... T>
struct S{
    template<int>
    struct A{};

    template<T...>
    struct B{};

    template<template<T...> class>
    struct C{};
};

S<int>::C<S<int>::B> s1;
S<int>::C<S<int>::A> s2;//gcc5.1.0 fails, clang3.6.0 succeeds

int main(){}
```

you can test here http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/hhy70gO9LMjLq9nU

Which one is right, gcc or clang?

Comment: It's a GCC bug. You can file a report [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved in gcc 6.0